# gnome session flashback ubuntu 18.04 panel multi monitor

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors as extended desktop with my laptop.
Gnome shell is so heavy that makes my laptop is so laggy and slow.

```
jarvis
    description: Notebook
    product: 80Q6 (LENOVO_MT_80Q6_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad 300-14ISK)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo ideapad 300-14ISK
    serial: PF0EU4F2
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80Q6_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad 300-14ISK uuid=61BD782B-1181-E511-BA4C-507B9D5FDEBB
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Paris 4A8
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: NO DPK
       serial: PF0EU4F2
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: D5CN28WW
          date: 08/13/2015
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 6016KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2184MHz
          capacity: 2800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 64KiB
             capacity: 64KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 64KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 26
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: CMSO4GX3M1C1600C11
             vendor: AMI
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: M471B5173EB0-YK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 2
             serial: 18203810
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 3
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:a1300000-a130ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-72-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB Gaming Mouse
                   vendor: Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.20
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB Receiver
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 30.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: Lenovo EasyCamera
                   vendor: Bison Corp.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 43.53
                   serial: 200901010001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: USB2.0-CRW
                   vendor: Generic
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 39.60
                   serial: 20100201396000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:4
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: Bluetooth Radio
                   vendor: Realtek
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 2.00
                   serial: 00e04c000001
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-72-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:a132a000-a132afff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:128 memory:a132b000-a132bfff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:a1328000-a1329fff memory:a132e000-a132e0ff ioport:6080(size=8) ioport:6088(size=4) ioport:6060(size=32) memory:a132c000-a132c7ff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:a1200000-a12fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: enp1s0
                version: 15
                serial: 50:7b:9d:5f:de:bb
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.60.36.60 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:16 ioport:5000(size=256) memory:a1204000-a1204fff memory:a1200000-a1203fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:a1100000-a11fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 00
                serial: 18:4f:32:94:67:b5
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.15.0-72-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.42.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:130 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a1103fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:a1000000-a10fffff ioport:80000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: Display controller
                product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 83
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
                resources: irq:131 memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:a1000000-a103ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1040000-a105ffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a1324000-a1327fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:132 memory:a1320000-a1323fff memory:a1310000-a131ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:a132d000-a132d0ff ioport:6040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST1000LX015-1U71
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: SDM1
             serial: WQ95VSLD
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=8a1f0954-be5a-4ee7-8db3-a5a6faa98b46 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 1
                serial: 4e67a63c-7467-406e-b959-b7957a6ddeb0
                size: 1951MiB
                capacity: 1951MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: e5bf-31ce
                size: 511MiB
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: da25a92f-5d14-4d7a-baa7-b0b702606fab
                size: 929GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2019-11-30 21:36:12 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2020-01-02 12:49:03 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2020-01-02 12:49:05 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM UJ8HC
             vendor: MATSHITA
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: G801
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       description: Zinc Air Battery
       product: CRB Battery 0
       vendor: -Virtual Battery 0-
       physical id: 1
       version: 08/08/2010
       serial: Battery 0
       slot: Fake
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:69:7d:99:61
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: br-9b57ba3b90f1
       serial: 02:42:8c:83:b2:0d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.19.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: br-cbcc370fb4fe
       serial: 02:42:7a:af:cf:a6
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.18.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

I am a web developer with Jetbrains environment like phpstorm and datagrip.
I also use docker.

So I decide to use gnome session flashback.
Lucky, everything is OK & smooth.

But my question is, can I have a panel in each desktop monitor.

Comment: Try the "Multi-monitor" Gnome Shell extension (not sure whether that will do it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Alt + Right click on existing panel -> New Panel. You can move new panel to other monitors with Alt + Left click.